# How to resolve stackoverflow error in android?

Tags: android

In past I have an Android smartphone with api level 26 and 3GB ram. On that device, my app works very fine. It didn't crash. But I just bought new smartphone with api level 30 and 6GB ram. It also has UNISOC octa core processor. But on that device my android app crashed randomly with stackoverflow error.

What is the solution for this error and what are its causes I cannot guess since logcat provide no information. And my main question is that, why it crashes on a smartphone with 6GB ram and why it don't crashes on a smartphone with 3GB ram?

**Edit 1:**
I found another interesting thing, when I switch to light theme, then it did't crash and when I switch to dark theme then it crashed.

Comment: A stackoverflow error is caused by an infinitely recursive loop 99.999% of the time.  Look at the logcat, figure out what functions are looping, and figure out why it isn't eventually exiting.

Comment: When I set debuggable to false then only it crashes. And when I set debuggable to true, then it did not crashes. So that is why I cannot get any detailed info in logcat. So is there any alternate way to find the responsible functions that causes crash?

Comment: Debuggable controls whether or not you can hook up a debugger.  A logcat stack is created in either case.  What debugable=false does is remove the debug symbols from the apk

Comment: But it didn't crash when I set debuggable to true.

Comment: Hey, please see edit 1.

Comment: Actually, here's a question-  if you didn't get a stack trace, how do you know its a stack overflow exception?  The only way to know what the exception was is from a stacktrace.

Comment: I set debuggable to false and then attached device and opened logcat then I kept watch on the device and error and then saw that stackoverflowerror over there when my application is crashed on device.

Comment: That's the first line of the stack trace.  Do that again, and get the rest of it.